# How to convert csv file who's columns start from some line number into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv file which has some header part and then actual columns start I have to read columns of this file. Example file shown below:

```
$$NAME$$ AKSHAY
$$School$$ SDSU 
$$Department$$ Computer Science
$$GPA$$   Red ID    TPA    CN       PHY
               1    3.9    2.8      2.5
               2    3.1    3.2      2.7
               3    3.5    3.6      3
```

File contains more than thousand lines, I am showing only 3 here.

I am using following code for reading csv file:

```
data= pandas.read_csv(data_file, skiprows=3)
```

It's giving me error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 23: invalid start byte
```

Please suggest me a way to read this csv file and to create a pandas data frame

Comment: As a general rule, don't show a picture of a file open in a spreadsheet, copy and paste the actual text itself.

Comment: @DSM I have edited my question with actual data

Comment: That is ascii for `¡` (inverted exclamation, not lowercase i). Did you check the file for such a character? Did you try skipping the first 4 rows instead of 3, just to see if that does it? I suspect the header line having 6 fields and data having 4 might cause issues, so you could add those later.

Comment: @beroe Skipping first 4 rows work fine.